# How can I make my Rust program run at startup?

Tags: linux, windows, rust, operating-system, startup

I know about how to run programs at startup on Windows, but not Linux (even though I use Linux myself). Is there a library I can use which will automatically run my program at startup? I have tried Googling about it and couldn't find anything, the closest thing I found were Windows binding for Rust.

I want to minimize the amount of code I have to actually write because when I *do* write a lot of code, it ends up looking kind of messy, and I don't want the other people working on the project to suffer. That being said, all I am asking for is if there is a library for what I want to do or if there is a way to run my program at startup with minimal amounts of code.

Comment: Launching a program isn't part of the program. It's part of the platform. There is no library you can use that would make a global change to your platform. It seems you haven't fully understood the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't see why there would not be a library which makes changes to the platform. I see programs auto-start on windows all the time so why is there no library for it?

Comment: This depends greatly on the Linux distribution and version. It shouldn't be something your program does, it should be something the person who creates a package for the specific distribution does or the user themselves. Also it's not clear what "at startup" means here exactly. Under Windows it normally means when a user logs in (unless you want a service), but this concept of a single login session doesn't exist in Linux. You could add yourself to something like `~/.profile` but then you get a new instance for every login shell. There is no universal answer, so I guess we'll need more info.

Comment: I see, by startup I do mean when the user logs in. I heard that you can use `~/.Xprofile` for that but I'm not 100% sure. I'll look into it.

Comment: Auto-start is not a feature of a program. You cannot compile anything into your binary that would automagically turn it into something the OS will launch in response to some event. You have to configure the system to do that. That's commonly done by an installer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution because it depends on your user's Linux distribution, its version, your user's desktop environment and *its* version (or if the user logs in with a text console or through the network). Plus, what should happen if the user logs in multiple times? Should the program run once for each session? Or once overall for each user?

Things you can look at:

- [`~/.Xprofile`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xprofile)
- [`~/.xinitrc` and `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinit#xinitrc)
- [`~/.config/autostart` and `/etc/xdg/autostart`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Autostart)
- [`~/.config/systemd/user/session.target.wants` or `~/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/User)

And more generally: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Autostarting

Answer (score 0):

Try pm2

It supports:

1. start at boot time of server.
2. logging,
3. remote monitoring.
4. works everywhere.

As other ppl mentioned start at boot time is nothing what your application should care about.